# summing along different axis returns same shape in numpy.sum

Tags: python-3.x

In the following code why `c` and `d` return same shape although summation is taken along different axis. When I sum along zero axis shape should be 1 row and 2 columns.

```
a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
c=np.sum(a,axis=0)
d=np.sum(a,axis=1)
print c.shape
print d.shape
```

Comment: The result will be different if `a.shape[0] != a.shape[1]` ;)

Comment: I tried with different number of  rows and columns and it gives (2,) (3,). Does it mean that I get 2 rows even after summing along row axis?it should return (,2) columns

Comment: Ah I understand what you mean now: The dimensionality will be reduced. The dimension that you aggregate across will miss in the result. So aggregating (like with `np.sum`) across an `n`-dimensional array will lead to a `n-1`-dimensional result.